# No response when I speak to Speech Recognition

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, pyaudio, portaudio

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
#
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("google speech recognition thinks you said " + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknowValueError:
    print("google speech recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from google speech recognition service;{0}".format(e))
```

macOS Mojave.

portaudio-19.6.0

pyaudio-0.2.11

After running python main.py, I said something to my mac and waited for few minutes. NO response at all!
Control+C to stop the process, and error message below.

```
Say something!
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 620, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 161, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: I've experienced something similar moving to MacOS Mojave. I think the issue could be that Mojave needs to give permission in order for applications to access the microphone. I have tried running my app as root but so far this has not worked either... I'd be interested to know if you solved this..?

Comment: OK I solved my issue. It was a permissions problem like I described. If I run my script in Terminal instead of iTerm2 I get asked to grant the app permissions.. I suppose this is an issue for iTerm2 to address. Hope this helped?

Comment: Is that works in terminal after granting the permissions? I didnt try before, I'd like to have a try tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using python 3.9 through PyCharm on macOS Mojave.

In order for applications and programs to use the microphone, macOS must grant it permission to do so, hence there was no audio input and no response upon running the script.

That being said in order to resolve this, you have to open ***System Preferences> Security & Privacy>Microphone*** and check the appropriate program to allow microphone use.

Bear in mind my case involves PyCharm as the application running the script, so under the microphone permissions I granted PyCharm access to my microphone and was prompted to restart the IDE.

After that the issue was resolved.

Comment: I wonder how you granted access? For me, this is not possible, since I need a request from VS code to grand access. There is not button in the preferences to simply add a program..